As a Noahide, can I wear a kippah or anything else
I converted to Noahidism but my appearance screams Turkish and so I am also associated with Islam. I therefore wanted to make it clear that I am not a Muslim in some way so I was wondering if I could wear a kippah or a Star of David or anything that can make it clear that I am not a Muslim in any case.

I don't think there's a halacha against anyone wearing a kippa or star of david! However, I suspect this question will be closed because it is a personal situation that would need to be discussed with someone who can get to know you personally, as it's not just a halachic issue. Is it possible for you to reach out to your nearest local orthodox Rabbi? I hear that might be tough in Turkey, if that's where you are currently located, so perhaps consider writing to Chabad through their website?

@RabbiKaii, there are Ashkenazi and Sephardi communities in Turkey and I presume that their rabbanim or ba'alei bayit supervise the many kosher products from there

The Ashkenazi Chief Rabbi is an extrordinarily public figure and quite open to dialogue...but, as in most Muslim countries, conversion to any religion but Islam is davka illegal and he would likely have to keep his distance from a self-proclaimed Noahide

I live in the Netherlands currently. In Turkey was it not a problem to be Noachist. Even my religious culture and ethics didn't say anything. Everyone in the Netherlands sees me automatically as a Muslim. I don't want it.

@NesiatWaqt there are some very good Rabbis in Amsterdam who would gladly help you, good luck!
